# Escape "<" in gedit while editing a *.md file

Tags: github, syntax-highlighting, markdown, gedit

I'm writing code examples in *.md format to be used on github, but I currently have not found a way to escape the `<` operator in `Python` code blocks:

````
```Python
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print i
```
````

This changes all text after `< 10:\n` to purple. Example below:

[image]

I have tried escaping it with `\` like so: `while i <\ 10:`, but this slash remains visible after uploading it to github and that is unintended, since it invalidates the code.

How do you solve this?

EDIT: @Blender suggested indenting the code instead of using ```Python blocks. This produces a similar response from gedit:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you indent it by four spaces? This looks like an issue with Gedit's syntax highlighter.

Comment: Could you elaborate what should I indent by four spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only viable solution to solve this annoyance was a mandatory comment closing the bracket after each occurrence of of a less than sign "<", like so:

````
```Python
i = 0
while i < 10: # >
    i += 1
```

Color stays the way it should be.
````

1. This solve the color change on gedit
2. Code blocks remain error free
3. Github renders everything fine

I choose this as an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiline code, indent it with four spaces (exactly like you do on StackOverflow, which uses Markdown):

```
Here is some sample Python code:

    def foo(bar, *args, **kwargs):
        print bar, args, kwargs

Here is some more text.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This would a solution if there would be an efficient way to indenting multiline block in gedit? Or am I missing something.

Comment: @MorganWilde: I'm not too sure what you're asking here. You can indent multi-line code by just highlighting it and pressing Tab (or Ctrl+], I think).

Comment: indenting produces a similar outcome as before, see question. Disregard my previous comment, it's irrelevant now. Also, github doesn't highlight the code as before.

Answer (score -1):

May be an htmlentity code will be fine : `&lt;`

Comment: This produces `while i &lt;` on github.